# unity - how to make a sprite fade-in gradually from one side to another

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

As above, on Unity, how to make a 2D sprite fade in (gradually increasing alpha) from one side (e.g. top) to another (e.g. bottom)?

Comment: I think the only way is to write a shader.

Comment: hi imapler can u give me more specific instruction?

Comment: I would suggest you research the subject, try something yourself, then come back and ask a more specific question.

Comment: ok I'll explore unity shader a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Once you learn a bit how to create custom shaders (you can use the built-in Unity 2018.1+ [ShaderGraph](https://blogs.unity3d.com/es/2018/02/27/introduction-to-shader-graph-build-your-shaders-with-a-visual-editor/), it's really handy and easy to use) all you had to do is multiply a gradient with aa input value and then connect the node to the alpha of your material.

Additionally, you can change the blending mode (Multiply,Add,Substract, etc...) in order to try different effects.